# Getting rid of cmd-windows for git gui on Windows 7

Tags: git, user-interface, windows-7, msysgit

Each time I start git gui a cmd-window is briefly shown for each of the unstaged files. This also happens when I click on a file or unstage it. This doesn't happen on Win XP.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these cmd-windows?

Answer (score 0):

This never happened for me on Windows 7. I think you are using the git.cmd wrapper rather than git.exe ( since the git and mingw binaries in msysgit may not be on your path)

Can you try adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` or wherever you installed msysgit to the path and call `git gui` and see? Or even explicitly call `git.exe gui`?

Comment: I am just throwing it out, since I never had this issue. So don't have your hopes high :)

Comment: Njet. I just checked with sysinternals process explorer on the W7 machine and compared with my xp machine. They are running the same binaries and its the git.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin